# After upgrade to 16.04, I can't add network Printer

Tags: 16.04, printing

[image: Screenshot]

Originally I had a network printer in my Printer setting, after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, the network printer doesn't appear in the list and the “Add” button is disabled.

How to resolve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check the cups status using either

```
#: systemctl status cups
```

or

```
#: service cups status
```

if cups isn't running yo can try and manually run it to see if it makes a difference, if cups isn't available maybe try installing it or reinstalling it

```
#: apt install cups
```

Comment: $ systemctl status cups

$ systemctl daemon-reload

$ sudo apt-get install cups

=> Now it works.